# How to use .save method in mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

```
 app.put('/app/modify/:_id', function(req, res) {
        Collection.findById(req.params._id, function (err, blog) {
            if (err) res.send(err);

            if (req.body.text1) blog.text1 = req.body.text1;
            if (req.body.text2) blog.text2 = req.body.text2;
            if (req.body.text3) blog.text3 = req.body.text3;
            if (req.body.text4) blog.text4 = req.body.text4;
            if (req.body.text5) blog.text5 = req.body.text5;

            Collection.save( function (err) {
                if (err) send (err);
                res.json({message: 'Blog Post Updated!'});
            });
        });
    });
```

Taken help from this - [PUT and DELETE - RESTful API Express MongoDB Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169674/put-and-delete-restful-api-express-mongodb-mongoose)

But getting error- http://localhost:8080/app/modify/59203c7d9532c34903000002 net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE and Node server stops with an error 'Collection.save is not a function'.

Comment: You mean `blog.save(function(err) { ...`. It's an instance method. IMHO It should not be used at all, but that's an entirely different subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it...

```
 app.put('/app/modify/:_id', function(req, res) {
            Collection.findById(req.params._id, function (err, blog) {
                if (err) res.send(err);

                if (req.body.text1) blog.text1 = req.body.text1;
                if (req.body.text2) blog.text2 = req.body.text2;
                if (req.body.text3) blog.text3 = req.body.text3;
                if (req.body.text4) blog.text4 = req.body.text4;
                if (req.body.text5) blog.text5 = req.body.text5;

                blog.save( function (err,response) {
                    if (err) res.json(err);
                    res.json({message: 'Blog Post Updated!'});
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thanx, now it is working but data is not getting update.Not showing any error.